# Passing data from EDT: is volatile necessary?

Tags: java, thread-safety

I have a background thread which will not start processing until it's `start` variable becomes `true`:

```
class MyBackgroundThread implements Runnable {
    // ...

    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            if(!start) continue;

            doSomethingWith(myValue);
        }
    }
}
```

The `start` variable is set to true from clicking a button on a `JFrame` which is of course running on the Event Dispatch Thread. There's also a `myValue` field in the background thread class, which is set from clicking the button:

```
startBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        backgroundThreadInstance.setMyValue(100);
        backgroundThreadInstance.setStart(true);

        // ...
    }
});
```

As you can see, it assigns something to `myValue` before setting `start` to `true`. Does this mean that setting `myValue` and `start` as `volatile` is not required? Since `myValue` is written to first, it will be leaked to the background thread before `start` is, thus the background thread will never get the chance to process an uninitialised `myValue`?

Comment: Instead of doing your own spin loop in `MyBackgroundThread`, why not use a `CountDownLatch`? Better yet, why not create a class that implements `Runnable` and has a constructor that takes an integer and pass that to an `ExecutorService` in `actionPerformed()` ?

Comment: `start` variable is still shared between two threads : `EDT` and `MyBackgroundThread` . So to make sure that the changed value of `start` within `EDT` is reflected for sure within `MyBackgrounThread` , You should use `volatile` keyword while declaring `start` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is yes.  Though, in practice, eventually the change to true would likely be seen by your thread, in theory it might never happen.

However, agree with @NamshubWriter that there are better ways to do this than an busy/idle loop.  I like his proposal to set the integer and then submit it to an ExecutorService.  e.g.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  BackgroundRunnableInstance runnable = new BackgroundRunnableInstance();
  runnable.setMyValue(100);  // could be in the constructor instead
  someExecutorService.submit(runnable);
}
```

One difference is that if they hit the button multiple times you would have several runnables started.  Which may or may not be what you want.